# Total all values from column of other table to another column of table

Tags: sql-server

I have datatable "tblTardiness" with values on each column "EmployeeName" and "TardinessPay".

EmployeeName    TardinessPay

Jay             53.42
Jay             30.20
Jay             20.03
Paul            53.42
Paul            53.42
Mike            20.03
Mike            20.03
Mike            53.42
Mike            20.03

another datable is "tblSalary" with values on column "EmployeeName" and empty or null value on "TardinessPay"

EmployeeName    TardinessPay

Jay             NULL
Paul            NULL
Mike            NULL

How can I compute each EmployeeName with total values of TardinessPay from "tblTardiness" and save automatically to "tblSalary".
See how looks like below

EmployeeName    TardinessPay

Jay             103.65
Paul            106.84
Mike            113.51

So far I used only Where clause by filtering each employee. but I need all employees at once. Please help me again guyz. Thank you!

Comment: `select a.EmployeeName,  sum( b.TardinessPay ) TardinessPay from tblSalary a left outer join tblTardiness b on b.EmployeeName = a.EmployeeName group by a.EmployeeName order by a.EmployeesName`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
select sum(TardinessPay) from tbltardiness group by EmployeeName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 select * from tblTardiness
```

EmployeeName         TardinessPay

---

Jay                  53.4200
Jay                  30.2000
Jay                  20.0300

```
 select * from tblSalary
```

EmployeeName         TardinessPay

---

Jay                  NULL

```
Update a set a.TardinessPay = b.pay from tblSalary a inner join (select EmployeeName,sum(TardinessPay) pay from tblTardiness group by EmployeeName) b on a.EmployeeName = b.EmployeeName


select * from tblSalary
```

EmployeeName         TardinessPay

---

Jay                  103.6500

Comment: Yeah...that's exactly what i want. You are great sir Sudhakar Singh. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can group by each employeename and sum their tardinesspay. Check this below query and hope it meets your requirement:

```
DECLARE @tblTardiness TABLE (EMPLOYEENAME VARCHAR(100), TARDINESSPAY NUMERIC(10,2))
DECLARE @tblSalary TABLE (EMPLOYEENAME VARCHAR(100), TARDINESSPAY NUMERIC(10,2))

INSERT INTO @tblTardiness VALUES('JAY',53.42),('JAY',30.20),('JAY',20.03),('PAUL',53.42),('PAUL',53.42),('MIKE',20.03),('MIKE',53.42),('MIKE',20.03),('MIKE',20.03)

INSERT INTO @tblSalary
SELECT EMPLOYEENAME, SUM(TARDINESSPAY)
FROM @tblTardiness
GROUP BY EMPLOYEENAME

SELECT * FROM @tblSalary ORDER BY EMPLOYEENAME
```

Comment: Thanks to your ideas sir Paresh J but still lots of EmployeeName in the "tblTardiness". I just give 3 names for Jay, 2 for Paul and 4 for Mike. That is only example.